# Force Xcode to run post build script for each dependency

Tags: xcode

I have several Xcode C++ utility projects which all have their own scheme, in which I have set up a post build script action.  This script takes up the Xcode project file and sorts it's content (so I have far less merge conflicts with Git).  I'm using a post-build action on the scheme instead of a run script build phase on the target itself, since modifying the project file from within a build phase script causes warnings/errors/dialogs IIRC.  This presumably because Xcode at that time is still busy with the build, and sees his project file changing during the build.  Doing it from the scheme doesn't give these issues.  So far so good.

The number of these projects has now grown a bit out of hand, so I have introduced an 'All' project (with its own 'All' target and scheme) that has a dependency on all of these projects, so I can more easily build them all in one go.  I've added all utility projects as subprojects on that "All" project (by drag/dropping them from Finder onto the 'All' project), and listed all these subprojects as a dependency.  However, when I build the 'All' target via it's own 'All' scheme, I noticed that Xcode doesn't run the post build actions of the utility projects' schemes at all.  Which could well be by design, since they're defined on the scheme level and we're in another scheme right now?

Question: how can I force Xcode to run this script for each utility project after the build has completed?  I don't mind if this happens all in one go after the last project builds, or if it happens for each project separately.

- A Run Script build phase is thus not an option, unless I'm overlooking something here.
- I could duplicate and concatenate the content of each utility's post build action into the post build action of the 'All' scheme, but:

  - That gives duplicated maintenance.
  - Right now the sorting script is ran in the context of the utility target itself, so I can just pass `${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}` to it for all utilities.  Concatenating the script calls in the 'All' target means I'd have to hard code the individual project file paths too.
- I can't switch to make files since other developers here strongly prefer the Xcode environment.
- I could also use Git pre-commit hooks, but they can't be committed to Git themselves, so that gives maintenance issues when cloning the repo to all the other machines over here.

Is there a better way to achieve this?